# Error: Objeto ha sido destruido

Tags: c#, unity

Cuando trato de ejecutar mi juego me sale el siguiente error:

> MissingRefferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Aquí esta mi código pero a decir verdad no se porque sucede el problema o a que se deba exactamente el problema.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DisparoMovimiento : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    private Transform playerTrans;

    private Rigidbody2D DisparoRB;

    public float DisparoSpeed;

    public float bolitalife;


    void Awake(){
        DisparoRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); 
        playerTrans = player.transform;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (playerTrans.localScale.x > 0){
            DisparoRB.velocity = new Vector2(DisparoSpeed, DisparoRB.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
        else{
            DisparoRB.velocity = new Vector2(-DisparoSpeed, DisparoRB.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿En que linea te muestra el error?

Comment: @Jorgesys en la linea donde tengo el `void update(){}`

Comment: Este problema es por que cuando intenta acceder al gameobject Player no encuentra un objecto. Comprueba si has **arrastrado el prefab del objecto a la variable player** o has **escrito bien el nombre tag en el Find** o **tienes puesto el tag en el player**. El código lo tienes bien pero te falta asignar esa variable. Ya nos dices. ¡Suerte!

Comment: @ASASCED Update() no tiene nada dentro?, si es así, agregalo, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tu gameObject no esta cogiendo bien la referencia, ya sea por haberla modificado o por haber actualizado Unity, prueba a referenciarselo otra vez o a crear el gameobject de nuevo agregandole el mismo script y la referencia. Puede que no veas ningun cambio por que el update esta vacio, prueba a ponerle algo